# .net 7 Razor pages with multiple route conventions not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, razor-pages, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I got an old .net4.8 web app that uses MVC and controllers and trying to convert(Rewrite) it to .net 7 razor pages.

I am trying to change the old url routing to be a standard.

My Razor page routeing works fine and is as follows.

```
@page "/flights/{FromIata:length(3)?}/{ToIata:length(3)?}"
```

i have also tried

```
@page "/flights/{FromIata?}/{ToIata?}"
```

in my program.cs I added the other route conventions.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(ops => { ops.Conventions.Insert(0, new RouteTemplateModelConventionRazorPages()); })
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/from-{FromIata:length(3)}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/{FromIata:length(3)}-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/{FromIata:length(3)}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/from-{FromIata:length(3)}-{FromCity}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}-{ToCity}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/to-{ToIata:length(3)}-{CityName}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights", "/flights/{*url}");
                })
```

if I browse to the page with the standard convection it works fine but if i use any of the other conventions I get a 404 error.

What I am trying to do is either load the page with the other convention.
i.e /Flights/to-kul-kuala%20lumpur
or if i use that conventions it does a permanent redirect to the new url format.
i.e Flights/kul

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solutions was as above to remove the /

```
@page "flights/{FromIata:length(3)?}/{ToIata:length(3)?}"
```

and add index to the convention.

```
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/Flights/from-{FromIata:length(3)}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/Flights/{FromIata:length(3)}-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/Flights/{FromIata:length(3)}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/Flights/from-{FromIata:length(3)}-{FromCity}-to-{ToIata:length(3)}-{ToCity}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/Flights/to-{ToIata:length(3)}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/flights/to-{ToIata:length(3)}-{CityName}");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Flights/Index", "{Culture}/flights/{*url}");
```

Answer (score 2):

The route template that you provided to the `@page` directive begins with a forward slash. This makes it an [override route](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes), which negates all others. If you want to add other route templates, remove the leading forward slash:

```
@page "flights/{FromIata:length(3)?}/{ToIata:length(3)?}"
```

Comment: and adding index to the convention

Comment: @Trevor yes, if the page is actually Index.cshtml. But there is no way to know that from your question.